# SwiftUI List Item Increase Count

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I want to put counters in every row and they are independent from each other. I can not do this with the code below. How can I implement this?

```
NavigationView {
        List {
            VStack{
                @State var number=0;
                Text(\(number))
                Button(action: { number+=1 }) { Text("increase") }
            }
            VStack{
                @State var number=0;
                Text(\(number))
                Button(action: { number+=1 }) { Text("increase") }
            }
            VStack{
                @State var number=0;
                Text(\(number))
                Button(action: { number+=1 }) { Text("increase") }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Counters")
    }
```

Comment: If the counters are independent, you can create 3 separates `number` variables

Comment: The declarations can’t be in the body they have to be outside

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the state for each counter outside of the `body` function and change them from within each button.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var number1 = 0
    @State var number2 = 0
    @State var number3 = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                VStack {
                    Text("\(number1)")
                    Button(action: { number1 += 1 }) { Text("increase") }
                }
                VStack {
                    Text("\(number2)")
                    Button(action: { number2 += 1 }) { Text("increase") }
                }
                VStack {
                    Text("\(number3)")
                    Button(action: { number3 += 1 }) { Text("increase") }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Counters")
        }
    }
}
```